# Execute Reader return Nothing always when I pass GUID as paramter

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim objconn As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(sConnStr)
        Dim objcmd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sSpName, objconn)
        Try

        objcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        objcmd.Parameters.Add(prmId)
        objconn.Open()
        Dim myReader As SqlDataReader
        If objconn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            myReader = objcmd.ExecuteReader()

            'myReader = objcmd.ExecuteReader()
            If myReader.HasRows Then
                If myReader.Read() Then
                    myFile = New File(myReader)
                End If
            End If
        End If
```

Can Any one suggest me. what would be wrong in the above code. ExecuteReader is throwing excepion. Invalid cast from string to GUID. But My Sqlparamter was already uniqueidentifier nothing cast. Any Idea?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetFileInfo     
@Id uniqueidentifier 
AS 
BEGIN 

 SELECT Id, DI_ID, sFileName, ContentType FROM FilesUpload Where Id=@Id
```

Comment: Please provide a more complete code snippet. At least how you pass the parameters, and to which stored procedure or sql command.

Comment: CREATE PROCEDURE GetFileInfo
 
 @Id uniqueidentifier
 
AS
BEGIN

here is the stored procedure
  SELECT
         Id,
 DI_ID,
 sFileName,
 ContentType
FROM
 FilesUpload
Where Id=@Id

Comment: @user993935 be sure to mark the 'best' answer with the green checkmark on all your questions. It's part of the reputation system on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

The value in your variable `prmId` is not a GUID, or rather, needs to be specified as such.

```
Using conn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("YourConnectionString")
    Using cmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand()

        cmd.CommandText = "GetFileInfo"
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier)
        cmd.Parameters("@Id").Value = New Guid(prmId)
        conn.Open()

        Dim myReader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        If myReader.Read() Then
            myFile = New File(myReader)
        End If
    End Using
End Using
```